# Robustness and maintanability based on descriptiveness of variables and docstrings

Tags: python

I got the point of PEP8 naming conventions, docstrings going inside methods, catching exceptions and printing them, not doing import *. will correct them.

I need a bit of advice on the robustness and flexibility for the following code.  Do you find the variable names descriptive and the flow of code optimal?

```
import config_files
from filter_tweets import *
from tweets import *
from twitter import *
from MongodbConnections import MongodbConnections
import importlib
import sys
from datetime import datetime
debugger = importlib.import_module('config_files.debugger')

"""
Uses twitter api to stream data from twitter and storing scored tweets and users into the mongodb database
"""
class scan_twittosphere:
    """
    Method description: Constructor 
    input:
            String: Keyword
            Object: Twitter api object
            Object: Config file object
            String: User key token
            String: User key secret
            String: Environment of execution
    output: None
    """

    def __init__(self, screen_name, keyword, api, config, key, secret, env):
        self.screen_name = screen_name
        self.keyword = keyword
        self.api = api
        self.config = config
        self.key = key
        self.secret = secret
        self.MongoObj = MongodbConnections(env)

    """
    Method description: Return Twitter API object
    input: None
    output: 
            Object: Twitter API
    """
    def getTwitterAPIobj(self):
        twitter_api_obj = Twitter(
                        auth=OAuth(self.key, self.secret,
                                   self.config.application_consumer_key, self.config.application_consumer_secret)
                       )
        return twitter_api_obj

    """
    Method description: Retrieves tweet objects using Twitter API seach function
    input: 
            String: Language
            String: Keyword
            String: Search type for User/Tweets

    output: None
    """    
    def searchTwitter(self, lang, keyword, type_search):
        #debugger.info("arrive searchTweets",config.debug)
        twitter_api_obj = self.getTwitterAPIobj()

        since_ID = -1
        max_ID = 0

        while(since_ID != max_ID):
            #debugger.info("arrive stream tweets2",config.debug)
            if lang == "ww":    
                search = twitter_api_obj.search.tweets(q = keyword, count = 100, since_id = max_ID)
            else:
                search = twitter_api_obj.search.tweets(q = keyword, lang = "en", count = 100, since_id = max_ID)

            if len(search['statuses']) == 0:
                debugger.info("arrive stream tweets4",self.config.debug)
                #print 'end'
                break

            since_ID = search['search_metadata']['since_id_str']
            max_ID = search['search_metadata']['max_id_str']

            tweets_obj = Tweets(self.config, self.MongoObj.getBadwordCol())
            self.insertAllobj(tweets_obj, search, type_search,keyword)


    """
    Method description: Inserts filtered object to the database
    input: 
            Object: Tweets
            Object: Tweets class object 
            String: Search type for User/Tweets
            String: Keyword
    output: None
    """    
    def insertAllobj(self, tweets_obj, search, type_search,keyword):
            for tweet in search['statuses']:
                if type_search == 'tweet':
                    debugger.info("score tweets",self.config.debug)
                    result = tweets_obj.score_tweet(tweet,keyword)
                    if result[0] == True:
                        self.insertTweet(tweet,result,keyword)

                elif type_search == 'user':
                    result = tweets_obj.score_user(tweet)
                    if result[0] == True:
                        self.insertUser(tweet,result,keyword)

    """
    Method description: This method executes Twitter API search for different languages
    input: 
            String: Keyword
            String: Search type for User/Tweets
    output: None
    """    
    def stream_tweets(self, keyword, type_search):
        debugger.info("arrive stream tweets",self.config.debug)
        self.searchTwitter("ww",keyword,type_search)
        self.searchTwitter("en",keyword,type_search)

    """
    Method description: Checks if the user exists in the database
    input: 
            Integer: user id
            String: Keyword

    output: Integer(0/1)
    """   
    def userExists(self,user_id):
        return self.MongoObj.getUsersIndex().find({'user_id': user_id}).count(True)
    """
    Method description: Checks if the tweet exists in the database
    input: 
            Integer: tweet id 
            Integer: user id

    output: Integer(0 or more)
    """   
    def tweetExists(self, tweet_id, user_id):
        return self.MongoObj.getTweetsIndex().find({'tweet_id': tweet_id}).count(True) + self.MongoObj.getTweetsIndex().find({'user_id': user_id}).count(True)

    """
    Method description: Inserts User in database
    input: 
            Object: tweet object 
            Mixed List (Boolean and Integer): result[True/False, Score] 

    output: None
    """    
    def insertUser(self,tweet, result,keyword):
        user_exist =  self.userExists(tweet['user']['id'])

        if user_exist == 0:

            self.MongoObj.getUsersIndex().insert({'user_id' : tweet['user']['id'], 'time':datetime.now()})        
            self.MongoObj.getUserFactoryCol().insert({'tweet': tweet['text'], 'tweet_id': tweet['id'], 'keyword': keyword, 'screen_name': tweet['user']['screen_name'], 'user_id': tweet['user']['id'], 'twittalikescore':result[1], 'time':datetime.now(), 'user_list':[]})
    """
    Method description: Inserts Tweet in database
    input: 
            Object: tweet object 
            Mixed List (Boolean and Float): result[True/False, Score] 

    output: None
    """    
    def insertTweet(self,tweet,result,keyword):
        tweet_exist = self.tweetExists(tweet['id'], tweet['user']['id'])

        if tweet_exist == 0:   
            '''
            add in master base
            '''
            self.MongoObj.getTweetsIndex().insert({'tweet_id': tweet['id'], 'user_id' : tweet['user']['id'], 'time':datetime.now()})
            self.MongoObj.getTweetFactoryCol().insert({'tweet': tweet['text'], 'tweet_id': tweet['id'], 'keyword': keyword, 'screen_name': tweet['user']['screen_name'], 'user_id': tweet['user']['id'], 'prediction': result[1],'twittalikescore':result[1],'time':datetime.now(), 'user_list':[]})
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Please wrap your code at column 80. Otherwise, we have to do a lot of sideways scrolling to read it. Besides, 79 byte lines is [what PEP8 recommends](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length).
2. Your variable and method names are quite descriptive.
3. Your method descriptions should go *inside* the method. For example, rather than this,

   ```
   """
   Method description: Return Twitter API object
   input: None
   output: 
           Object: Twitter API
   """
   def getTwitterAPIobj(self):
       twitter_api_obj = Twitter(
                       auth=OAuth(self.key, 
                                  self.secret,
                                  self.config.application_consumer_key,
                                  self.config.application_consumer_secret)
                      )
       return twitter_api_obj
   ```

   do this:

   ```
   def getTwitterAPIobj(self):
       """
       Method description: Return Twitter API object
       input: None
       output: 
               Object: Twitter API
       """
       twitter_api_obj = Twitter(
                       auth=OAuth(self.key, 
                                  self.secret,
                                  self.config.application_consumer_key, 
                                  self.config.application_consumer_secret)
                      )
       return twitter_api_obj
   ```

   Otherwise, pydoc will not put your descriptions in the right place. For example, when I run pydoc on your current file, the first method description shows up as the description of the entire class.
4. Your comments answer the question, "What does this method/program/set of lines do?" Often, the answer to that is obvious from the code, especially with method and variable names as descriptive as yours. I think comments are more useful when they answer *why* sorts of questions.

   For example, your first comment at the top of the file says, "Uses twitter api to stream data from twitter and storing scored tweets and users into the mongodb database." Okay, but does it pull in every single tweet ever? If not, what's the basis for selecting tweets to be stored? How are tweets scored? What's the relationship between tweets and users? Are the users the authors of the tweets or followers of the authors or what? Once we've stored all this information in Mongo, what are we going to do with it? What's the bigger picture that this piece of code fits into?